# Best way to multiply each row of a matrix by a random number

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I would like to multiply each row of a matrix by a random number e.g.

```
Y = R*X
```

with the diagonal matrix `R` of size `TxN` containing entries from `rand()` and the matrix `X` of size `NxM` with **very large** `T` and `N`. At the moment I use

```
r = rand(T)
Y = scale(r, X)
```

but I wonder if this be done faster or better. For example I think it is not necessary to create the vector `r`, but I don't know how I can call `y[i] = rand()*X[i,:]` efficiently/parallel.

Comment: In your case, how long does it take to create `r` compared to calling `scale()`?

Comment: You definitely want to create the temporary `r`. The reason: it is dreadfully inefficient to traverse `X` by rows, it's 5-10 times faster to traverse by columns. So in this case allocation of the temporary `r`, and traversing `X` by columns (i.e., in memory storage order), will be a huge win. Particularly if `X` and `r` are `Float32`, in which case this should SIMD vectorize.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scale!` to modify `X` in place:

```
julia> X = [ 1/(i + j - 1) for i=1:5, j=1:5 ]
5x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0       0.5       0.333333  0.25      0.2
 0.5       0.333333  0.25      0.2       0.166667
 0.333333  0.25      0.2       0.166667  0.142857
 0.25      0.2       0.166667  0.142857  0.125
 0.2       0.166667  0.142857  0.125     0.111111

julia> r = rand(5)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.98996
 0.88145
 0.808518
 0.632665
 0.00807468

julia> scale!(r,X);

julia> X
5x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.98996     0.49498     0.329987    0.24749     0.197992
 0.440725    0.293817    0.220363    0.17629     0.146908
 0.269506    0.20213     0.161704    0.134753    0.115503
 0.158166    0.126533    0.105444    0.0903807   0.0790832
 0.00161494  0.00134578  0.00115353  0.00100933  0.000897187
```

This avoids allocating a new matrix, which is a significant savings in both memory and time.

Comment: nice, +1 for `scale!`

Comment: Thx. Will scale! use multiple cores?

Comment: Currently it does not use multiple cores.